# Displaying a Forecast Widget on a website

Tags: python, web, widget, forecasting

I am looking for displaying Forecast information in my Django Website.
Do you have any idea of how I can do that ?

I looked at https://registration.weather.com/ursa/wow/ but it is in english and I didn't find anyway to put it in French.

I looked at libgweather, but it didn't helps me a lot.

Do you know how I can do that ?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is : http://france.meteofrance.com/france/accueil/partenaire

Comment: I don't know why it is always when I send my question that I finally find the answer ...